# Simple debug-level Python logging fails?

Tags: python, logging

Here's a bit of code I'm running under Python 3.3.2:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("test.logger")

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # Shouldn't be needed
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print("Effective logging level is {}".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.debug("This is a debug-level message.")
```

And here's the output:

```
Effective logging level is 10
```

So the debug message didn't get written, despite the fact that the logger's level appears to be correct. I don't see anything in the Python doc or on this site that suggests I'm missing anything. What's going on here? Thanks.

EDIT: If I exercise the root logger by adding this line ...

```
logging.debug("Try this")
```

... then both messages come out. (Note the use of `logging` instead of `logger`.) Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amber's answer is correct. I can tell you why you're seeing messages for `WARNING` or higher, but not `INFO` or `DEBUG`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) for 3.2:

> `logging.lastResort` - A “handler of last resort” is available through
>   this attribute. **This is a `StreamHandler` writing to `sys.stderr`
>   with a level of `WARNING`, and is used to handle logging events in the
>   absence of any logging configuration**. The end result is to just print
>   the message to `sys.stderr`. This replaces the earlier error message
>   saying that “no handlers could be found for logger XYZ”. If you need
>   the earlier behaviour for some reason, `lastResort` can be set to
>   `None`.

Note the section in bold above - that's the reason why you're not seeing messages below `WARNING`. Just add a line

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

before the `logger.debug(...)` line, and you'll see the `DEBUG` message appear.

When you call `logging.debug(...)`, this adds a `StreamHandler` to the root logger if there's no handler for it (as documented in the note just below [here](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.html#logging.log)), which is why both messages appear.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidation.

Answer (score 2):

The debug message *is* getting written, you just never added an actual log output method (either via [`.basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) or via [adding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler) a [`Handler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects) instance).

So no log messages will be displayed anywhere because you haven't told the logger where to display them.

Comment: If I use logger.warning or .error or .critical, I see the message. Only info and debug level messages are suppressed. It's as if the original level of 30 (logging.WARNING) is still being used.

Comment: I am having the same trouble as Tony. I have the same code on two different computers. One outputs the debug, and one does not. One Python 2.7.12 (fails) and the other Python 2.7.13 (works). Is there a logging problem for Python 2.7.12 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be testing an application for Google App Engine, then this problem is solved by adding `--log_level=debug` in the `dev_apperver.py` parameters